# Use CSV values in JMeter as request path

Tags: rest, csv, jmeter

I have one of jmeter User defined variable as a "comma separated value" - ${countries} = IN,US,CA,ALL .

(I was first trying to get it as a list/array - [IN,US,CA,ALL]  )

I want to use the variable to test a web service - GET /${country}/info . IS it possible using ForEach controller or Loop controller ?

Only thing is that I want to save it or read it as IN,US,..,ALL and use it in the request path.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The CSV should be as per the format mentioned in the image attached.
  [image: CSV Format]

Refer to the link on how to use CSV in Jmeter: http://ivetetecedor.com/how-to-use-a-csv-file-with-jmeter/

**Thread Group Settings**

**No. of threads:** 1
**Ramp-up period:** 1
**Loop Count:** 4

Hope this will help.

Comment: Yes you are talking about CSV config - which helps us to have multiple sets of values in a loop, one for every loop. i.e. The loop runs row wise (if csv is opened in excel)

Comment: Yes you are talking about CSV config - which helps us to have multiple sets of values in a loop, one for every loop. I wanted something different - to loop row wise. Separators would be for different values of same variable and new line would represent a new variable.
Why I would prefer this design is that I have some expected values for different variables e.g. country, state ... The count of these variables is not equal and they are not related to each other. So was looking for column wise looping and row wise variables. Not sure if that design is viable or not.

Comment: You can definitely achieve the design you have mentioned above, but for that you will have to write your own Java code in BeanShell Sampler or BeanShell Pre or Post processors.

Answer (score 0):

CSV config is a red herring, you don't need it.

You can use a regular expression extractor to split up the variable into another variable (eg MyVar), using something like:

```
(.+?)[,\n]
```

This is trying to match each item before a `,` or newline. It will place the values in variables like MyVar_1, MyVar_2, etc.  This is as close to an array as JMeter understands natively.

You can then loop on the contents of the matches using MyVar_matchNr, and MyVar_1 to MyVar_n (you will need to use __V() function to access the 'array' contents.